How to emphasise that you yourself CAN as opposed to the other person being able to, without using typography like capitals or italics in a sentence?
Yesterday I was writing a letter and I stumbled upon a linguistic issue that I couldn't solve in a more elegant way. As such I'm searching for an answer to this puzzle.
I'm Dutch and in my language we simply insert the Dutch word wel in a sentence, which essentially is a capitalised preposition expressing capability.
The sentence I was trying to write was in the context of a conflict with my employer where I wanted to say I was capable of something he isn't:

[...] Because as opposed to my employer I AM capable of exerting discretion and dignity.

How would I write this without using capital letters or any other typographic indicators like italics?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I’m voting to close this question because it's less about English language and usage, and more about which stylistic convention to adopt in a letter. It might (possibly) be a better fit on our other site Writing.SE.

There are so many ways to express in English what you wish to express, which is, as far as I understand it, something like "Unlike you [addressed to your employer] I can behave with discretion and dignity"  and you're looking for an intensifer to put in front of "behave".
You can approximate that meaning quite closely by changing "can" to "know how to":

Unlike you, I know how to behave with discretion and dignity.


That's a very elegant solution and EXACTLY what I was looking for. Truly appreciated! I suppose an even stronger intensifier would be 'unlike you, I do..'

I speak Dutch as a second language, and I suspect that this use of wel may be one reason why I often find myself seeking intensifying adverbs in English (my native language).  (Another useful feature of Dutch that I sometimes miss in English is the ability to add an accent at will simply to indicate emphasis, which in English traditionally requires italics or boldface type, or, in plain text contexts, all caps, as in the question.)
I tend to use certainly and, occasionally, indeed:

I am certainly capable of...

In this case, because of the sense of contradiction, I would probably prefer indeed:

Because, as opposed to my employer, I am indeed capable of exerting discretion and dignity.

To soften it slightly, you could use in contrast to instead of as opposed to.  To be clear, that is a point of style or of fine tuning.  If you do not want to sound more diplomatic, you can certainly leave it as it is.

It may be helpful for readers to know that wel functions in Dutch as the "anti-not," much like German doch.

vraag: je gaat zeker niet?!
antwoord: ik ga wel!

In this sense, colloquial English, in the US at least, uses too or so:

question: You're not really going?!
answer: I am so!

In a more formal register, this could be I certainly am! or indeed I am!


Because as opposed to my employer I AM capable of exerting discretion and dignity.

The phrase as opposed to sounds too indirect, so you might want to change it to something more direct such as unlike. This way, you can indirectly emphasize your capability. Also, exerting discretion and dignity should be replaced with something more idiomatic:

Because, unlike my employer, I am capable of exercising discretion in my actions and conducting myself with dignity.

If you still want more emphasis, you can also italicize am.

Because, unlike my employer, I am capable of exercising discretion in my actions and conducting myself with dignity.


Thank you for the clarification! To be comprehensive this is probably the 20th letter I've written to my employer as we've been engaged in a conflict for over a month. In that time my employer has disconnected my warm water, disabled my wet cell, harassed me and sent numerous false allegations and, more to the point, set up staff against me hence the remark about discretion and dignity. Could someone inform me about my bias against the use of italics or Capitals? I'm 49yo and I strongly feel this use of typography is youthful text message language which I dislike. Is this a wrong assumption?

PS. I'm new here so I don't know how to use upvotes and such. Please don't take this as unappreciative, it's simply me not knowing how to do this.

@phoog This is by far the most clear and satisfying answer to me. Thank you! Also the additional correct link to the German 'doch' is spot on. It's interesting all are Germanic languages yet the idiomatic use of certain words creates such nuance.
I feel my original question is answered. I'm still curious though about my feeling that typography is 'not done' in formal correspondence. Opinions?
As a side note I read a lot of (for me) typical English sentiment of being offended by the use of rude language. This seems to be a deeply rooted cultural element which might be in play as well ;)

@WishPlay An alternative approach might be one that provides clear prosodic emphasis merely by word choice or word- or phase-ordering alone, such as would be needed in speech and therefore without reliance on ‘crassly overwrought’ typographic tricks such as: (Aʟʟ-)Cᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟ Lᴇᴛᴛᴇʀꜱ,  or  or ⸗ ℴ; ᴏʀ decorative ‘typographic wallpapering’ such as /this/ or ✲this✲ or this; ᴏʀ ‘gaudy’ color-tricks; ᴏʀ cutesy-tootsie emoji ; ᴏʀ countless exclamation marks❗❗❗⸻That way it avoids looking like a ransom note. :)
